# Проверка определённого количества повторяющегося текста на python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

У меня не происходит проверка 2 нужных мне повторяющихся слов но ошибки нет! как мне это исправить?
Если конкретно с помощью global os считывается названия файлов с расширением mp4 и название записывается в переменную file
дальше создаётся текстовый файл (Videos.txt) который находится там же где находится моя программа в одной папке с перечислениями файлов которые записаны в переменную file с новой строки
дальше считываются все строки из текстового файла и происходит поиск именно двух повторяющихся слов записанных в переменную file если они находятся то программа закрывается если же нет программа продолжает работу

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import glob, os
import youtube_dl
import datetime
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

os.chdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/youtube-bot")

for file in glob.glob("*.mp4"):

    my_file = open("Videos.txt", "a+")
    my_file.write(str(file)+"\n")       
    my_file = open("Videos.txt")
    f = my_file.read()
    if file == 2 in f:
        exit(0)
    else:
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не совсем понимаю где у Вас "происходит поиск именно двух повторяющихся слов записанный в переменную file". + вы считываете файл вникуда, значение не присваивается ничему: my_file.read(). нужно f = my_file.read()

Comment: то есть примерно вот так? 
   f = my_file.read()
    if file == 2 in f:
      exit(0)
    else:

Comment: программа должна закрываться если там 2 повтора файлов или от 2? тоесть, если файл повторится 3 раза, программа закроется? просто не пойму что именно и где должно повторятся

Comment: программа закрывается после двух повторов если повторится два одинаковых слова присвоянных переменой file в videos.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно именно выходить при нахождении повтора. Сначала получаем список файлов, потом считываем файл построчно. если считанное из файла не в списке - добавляем в список, иначе - выходим. после можно перезаписать файл

```
os.chdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/youtube-bot")
res = glob.glob("*.mp4")

with open("Videos.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() in res:
            exit(0)
        else:
            res.append(line.rstrip())
with open("Videos.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in res:
        f.write(i+'\n')
```

Comment: мне бы именно с записью текста и нахождении двух строк если же ничего не находится то код просто продолжается

Comment: подправил. если программа не найдет одинаковых строк, перезапишет файл и пойдет дальше

Comment: куда можно подставить переменную file? у меня просто ещё и res не находится (извиняюсь за глупые вопросы)

Comment: ой извиняюсь не увидел res = glob.glob(*.mp4) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

самый простой вариант перезапись всего файла

```
x=open...
res=set(x)
x.write(res)
```

то есть переводим файл в список, который переовдив в сет, тем самым удаляя повторяющиеся строке, затем записываем результат.
Но, оптимальнее проверять наличие совпадений перед записью в файл

Comment: Можно пожалуйста конкретный пример для оптимального варианта?